# How to retrieve data from asp.net web app to windows forms app(.net framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

We have an asp.net project and what we want is that once we press a button on the web app, we d like to send .rar file to a windows form app on user's desktop which is also created by me. Right after we got the data from asp.net to the windows form app, we d like to process it and send it back to where it comes from(asp.net).

I would be glad if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: No web application can control anything on a desktop. That was turned off long ago for security reasons. A desktop app could certainly call a web API to do all of those things, if your web application supports some kind of web API

Answer (score 0):

We can share data between web app to windows form app by following ways.

1. To store data into Db from Web App and then retrieve data from DB in Windows App
2. To store file in shared location from Web App and get it from Windows App